# Evaluating $\int d^3\vec{r} {{\nabla}_{\vec{r}}^2 }$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential

Is $\int d^3\vec{r} {{\nabla}_{\vec{r}}^2 }$ equal to $\vec{\nabla}_{\vec{r}} + C$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus or should another method of proof be used?

Comment: Without specifying limits we would have

$$\begin{align}\sum_i\iiint \left(\frac{\partial^2 \{\cdot\}}{\partial x_i^2}\right)\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3&=\iint \left(\frac{\partial \{\cdot\}}{\partial x_1}+C_1\right)\,dx_2\,dx_3\\\\
&+\iint \left(\frac{\partial \{\cdot\}}{\partial x_2}+C_2\right)\,dx_1\,dx_3\\\\
&+\iint \left(\frac{\partial \{\cdot\}}{\partial x_3}+C_3\right)\,dx_1\,dx_2
\end{align}$$

Comment: You should provide context: where does this pop up? What are you trying to evaluate? One useful fact is [the divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) which gives you that $\int d^3r \nabla^2 F$ is equal to the surface integral of $(\nabla F)\cdot n$ over the boundary of your integration volume (and $n$ is the outwards pointing unit normal vector to the boundary surface).